# Unable to install Bio::SeqIO module on Ubuntu for Windows 10 from Microsoft Store

Tags: perl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bioperl

I used Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for Windows from Microsoft store and tried to install BioPerl module Bio::SeqIO with `cpanm Bio::SeqIO`. Perl version is v5.26.1. It seems that module installation failed:

```
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'XML::Twig' is not installed, Module 'XML::LibXNL::Reader' is not installed, Module 'XML::LibXML' is not installed, Module 'XML::Parser::PerlSAX' is not installed, Module 'XML::DOM::XPath' is not installed, Module 'XML::DOM' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for BioPerl-1.7.7
58 distributions installed
```

If i run a script with line use Bio::SeqIO; I get an error:

```
    Can't locate Bio/SeqIO.pm in @INC (you may need to install the 
        Bio::SeqIO module) (@INC contains: ...
```

I am not sure how to proceed. I could try to install dependencies that failed with cpanm but I do not know if it is a proper way.

Comment: What happens when you try to install XML::Twig (as noted in the first error message)?

Comment: I get failure with dependencies:  `Found dependencies: XML::Parser --> Working on XML::Parser ... ! Configure failed for XML-Parser-2.46. ! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'XML::Parser' is not installed`

Comment: It sounds like you need to install expat, the external library that XML::Parser needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this on my Windows 10 laptop:

- Installed WSL Ubuntu 18.10 as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), then
- Using the system `perl`, i.e `/usr/bin/perl` (maybe it would have been better to use `perlbrew` and installed a custom `perl` and such avoid using `sudo`) from the Linux terminal window:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get -y install make gcc libexpat1-dev
  sudo cpan local::lib
  sudo cpan App::cpanminus
  sudo cpanm -n Time::Zone  # <-- failed tests
  sudo cpanm -n XML::DOM::XPath # <-- failed tests
  sudo cpanm Bio::SeqIO
  ```

This worked for me.

Comment: Ah, the thing that doesn't stand out is the libexpat1-dev. That's the library the XML parsers need.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `sudo apt-get install bioperl bioperl-run` would install all modules which you might need in feature.

[Bioperl](https://bioperl.org/)